# advice sought on how to pass grouped parameters via QUERY_STRING in a REST app

Tags: rest

My backend app takes, say, three params to create an object and returns it as JSON

```
http://server/app/resource.json?a=foo&b=3&c=bar
```

I have another capability in my app that can take the object returned from the above URI and "transform" it into a different object. For now, I am doing the following

```
http://server/app/resource.json?a=foo&b=3&c=frob&transform_to=blarg
```

That doesn't seem very intuitive to me. I am wondering if I could do something like

```
http://server/app/resource.json?in={a:foo,b:3,c:frob}&out={c:blarg}
```

Would appreciate any advice on this.

Even more interesting would be if I could take the output from one URI and pass it as an input to another URI, but I guess we have a long way before we will get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in REST terms what you do is completely wrong for several reasons.

> I have another capability in my app that can take the object returned from the above URI and "transform" it into a different object.

You can have multiple representations of single resource, though "transforming" it to different object already means that you are speaking about different resource.

To fix this issue you at least need to create different resource which will produce different object. For example: http://server/app/brag.json?a=foo&b=3&c=bar

> http://server/app/resource.json?a=foo&b=3&c=frob&transform_to=blarg

You are encoding action (i.e. transform_to) directly into URL. This is not REST this is very usual RPC. You need to depend on uniform interface and use only GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods(verbs) in case of HTTP.

Again, creating different resource i.e. /blarg.json which accepts query parameters will be much cleaner and you will avoid passing actions in URLs.

> http://server/app/resource.json?in={a:foo,b:3,c:frob}&out={c:blarg}

this kind of parameter "{a:foo,b:3,c:frob}" doesn't make much sense. If your backend system knows on which parameters it depends, why not stay with this cleaner and far natural approach? "?a=foo&b=3&c=bar"

In this example transforming "&out={c:blarg}" to "&format=blarg" will partially fix action issue mentioned above, though this still means that your resource has two variations(not representations) of single media type(application/json in this case). This logically leads us to creating different resource rather than transforming existing one into different object.

> Even more interesting would be if I could take the output from one URI and pass it as an input to another URI, but I guess we have a long way before we will get there.

Yes it's absolutely legal but it depends how you will implement such behavior.

===========================================================================================

When working on RESTful web services based on HTTP protocol main goal is to rely on HTTP semantics and always avoid building additional rules atop of it. SOAP web services are good example of this(it doesn't mean that SOAP is bed etc...). SOAP always uses HTTP's POST method for communicating with server and encodes all parameters and actions in XML.

Comment: while you are correct that transforming a resource results in a different resource, hence, a different URI, it depends on where I am viewing it from. Think of a "timescale" resource that may exist in the "human" timescale (hours, days, weeks, months) vs. the "geologic" timescale (centuries, eras, eons). So, the same URI in geologic timescale with century = 1 has 5200 weeks in the human timescale. From the point of timescale as a resource, I am transforming it from human to geologic, so I need the same URI which returns a resource that can be "transformed" from one timescale to another.

Comment: on more thought, I am coming to terms with the above answer. If I get a representation of a resource with `http://server/app/resource.json?a=foo&b=3&c=frob` then `http://server/app/resource.json?a=foo&b=3&c=blarg` is simply another representation of the same resource... no need for a separate "transform_to" parameter. Thanks for your input.